# filter one dataframe by contents of each column of the second one

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I want to filter one dataframe by the contents of each separate column of the other, and produce a dataframe output from it.
First dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
sites_df <- data.frame(QC1 = sample(c(LETTERS[1:6],NA,NA), size =10, replace = T)
                       ,QC2 = sample(c(LETTERS[2:7],NA,NA), size =10, replace = T)
                       ,QC3 = sample(c(LETTERS[1:8],NA), size =10, replace = T))
```

It looks like this:

```
> sites_df
    QC1  QC2  QC3
1     A    D <NA>
2     D    D    E
3  <NA>    B    E
4     A    F <NA>
5     B    F <NA>
6     E    C    E
7  <NA>    G    E
8     C    G    B
9     F    C <NA>
10    B <NA>    A
```

Second dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
compartments <- data.frame(Protein = sample((LETTERS[1:8]), size =20, replace = T)
                           ,compartment = paste0("comp", LETTERS[1:4])) %>% 
  unique()
```

It looks like this:

```
> compartments
   Protein compartment
1        A       compA
2        D       compB
3        G       compC
4        A       compD
5        B       compA
6        E       compB
8        C       compD
9        F       compA
10       B       compB
11       C       compC
15       E       compC
16       B       compD
18       F       compB
19       B       compC
20       G       compD
```

For each column of the `sites_df`, I would like to know how many **unique** elements of this column are present in `compartments$Protein` column, and then summarise it as shown below. I can do it on a  column-by column basis:

```
# first, create a list of unique sites for a selected column
QC1_sites <- sites_df %>% 
  select(QC1) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  unique %>%
  deframe()


# then, filter the compartments object and calculate summary statistics 
QC1_comp <- compartments %>% 
  filter(Protein %in% QC1_sites) %>% 
  group_by(compartment) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  rename(QC1_comp = n) %>%  #last two lines needed for joining later
  ungroup()
```

I can then merge each individual objects (`QC1_comp`, `QC2_comp`, etc.)  into a dataframe, by using one of the `join()` functions and joining by `compartment`.

Desired output:

```
  compartment QC1_comp QC2_comp QC3_comp
1 compA              3        2        2
2 compB              4        3        2
3 compC              3        3        2
4 compD              3        3        2
```

With larger dataframes, this becomes impossible to do column-by-column.

If it helps, I could also have a list of character vectors instead of my original dataframe `sites_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do it like this:

```r
sapply(sites_df, function(site) 
  table(factor(compartments$compartment)[compartments$Protein %in% site]))

#       QC1 QC2 QC3
# compA   3   2   2
# compB   4   3   2
# compC   3   3   2
# compD   3   3   2
```

I used `factor` there so that possible zero occurrences would not be omitted by `table`.